# Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes. Google Drive

Tags: java, spring, oauth, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

i tries to add member to my google sheet using java code, but it doesn't work.

I use OAuthor 2.

Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks very much.

My code:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    final String spreadsheetId = "10gLncj6bGmm-UcXP1vztsbv23CD85GNG95zjDgZ8HBA";
    

    JsonBatchCallback<Permission> callback = new JsonBatchCallback<Permission>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(GoogleJsonError e,
                              HttpHeaders responseHeaders)
                throws IOException {
            // Handle error
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Permission permission,
                              HttpHeaders responseHeaders)
                throws IOException {
            System.out.println("Permission ID: " + permission.getId());
        }
    };
    Drive driveService = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
    BatchRequest batch = driveService.batch();
    Permission userPermission = new Permission()
            .setType("user")
            .setRole("reader")
            .setEmailAddress("trilo10101990@gmail.com");
    driveService.permissions().create(spreadsheetId, userPermission)
            .setFields("id")
            .queue(batch, callback);
    batch.execute();
}
```

Out put :

```
Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you are using for authorization.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

Means that the user you have authenticated the application with has not granted your application enough scopes to access the data you are trying to access.

You appear to be using [Permissions.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) this method requires that the user be authorized with one of the following scopes

[image]

You didn't post all of your authorization code You probably have something like this.

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
    .Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets,
        DriveScopes.all()).setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory)
    .build();
```

The trick is to look for which scope you are requesting in the case of the code above it is requesting full access to google drive.  You need to check your scope and ensure that you have requested full access.

After that you need to remove the users consent to your application and force it to request access of the user again.  The user needs to see the consent screen in order to verify their consent.

Comment: Thank you very much DalmTo.  Can you help me , how to remove the users consent to my application?

Comment: That's hard to say without seeing your auth code, you are probably storing the access token and refresh token someplace.  However you can do it directly though the users google account https://myaccount.google.com/permissions?pli=1  just look for your app name and remove it.

Comment: Thank you. I removed scope access. Get a new OAuthor code. And run again. then it shows another error :                                                                                          
                                                                                                                            
          Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant",
  "error_description" : "Token has been expired or revoked."
}

Comment: exactly you need to remove it in your code now.  Your still running with the old refresh token and your code isnt set up to force a reauthrozation.

Comment: DalmTo do you know how to edit the style of cells(color, boder, merger ...)

Comment: probably something to do with [cellformat](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#cellformat)  I have something that does it using C# open a new question if you have trouble and i will have a look.